# How to change Component Template of components in XPM Edit mode?

Tags: experience-manager

How could we change the CT name used for on Components in XPM Mode(Site Edit Mode through XPM). Is there any option?

Comment: The question is change the Component Template of a Component in XPM or the CT Name of the component?

Answer (score 3):

In XPM,

- Select the Component presentation
- remove the Lock if required.
- then go to layout Tab
- Keep it in small mode, (seems issue in Expanded mode)
- You will see the available component template to update

Thanks @Raul for providing feedback.

Comment: I disagree with this. You can change the Component Template of a component presentation in XPM within the "Layout" menu item, if a component presentation is selected.

Comment: thanks @RaúlEscudero , actually i was not able to see in expanded mode. seems a xpm issue. now i have updated my answer.  Really appricate!!